# How to separate surnames (upper cases) and first names (lower cases) in a single string using a regular expression in Python?

Tags: python, regex

I'm doing this exercise:

> In this case, the surnames are written in capital letters (upper
> cases) and are placed before the first names.
>
> Surnames can contain multiple names and can be separated by a space or
> hyphen (-). Surnames can contain lowercase prepositions (Di, Mac).
>
> Sometimes the first name and surname can appear without a space.
>
> A person can have multiple names.

I try these strings in rows divided into groups. => The first group of surnames (upper cases). The second group of names (lower cases).

Test input:

```
DiCAPRIO Leonardo Wilhelm

MacGYVER Angus

ANDERSON Richard Dean

ZETA-JONES Catherine

BONHAM CARTER Helena

DOUGLASMichael
```

Output (how it should look):

```
["DiCAPRIO"], ["Leonardo Wilhelm"]

["MacGYVER"], ["Angus"]

["ANDERSON"], ["Richard Dean"]

["ZETA-JONES"], ["Catherine"]

["BONHAM CARTER"], ["Helena"]

["DOUGLAS"], ["Michael"]
```

I have a regular expression:

`([A-Z]{2,}\s?\-?[A-Z]{2,}|[A-Z]{2,})`

(This regular expression works on https://regex101.com)

And I use the function `re.findall()`.

In Python 3.x:

```
for author in arrayAuthors:
    print(re.findall(r'([A-Z]{2,}\s?\-?[A-Z]{2,}|[A-Z]{2,})', author))
```

In a Python script, it only catches a surname composed of two names and a surname with a hyphen.

```
["ZETA-JONES"], ["Catherine"]

["BONHAM CARTER"], ["Helena"]
```

Other names return undivided:

```
["DiCAPRIO Leonardo Wilhelm"]

["MacGYVER Angus"]

["ANDERSON Richard Dean"]

["DOUGLASMichael"]
```

Comment: I cannot reproduce the output you describe. If I run this code, I get `['CAPRIO'] ['GYVER'] ['ANDERSON'] ['ZETA-JONES'] ['BONHAM CARTER'] ['DOUGLASM']` (on separate lines). Also confirmed by regex101: https://regex101.com/r/MhGhkq/1

Comment: I use IDE Spyder. I'll try testing in another IDE. What I noticed was that function ignored the expression behind the pipe (|).

Comment: Matching the names in the example data, see this example https://ideone.com/39EDhK

Comment: This question is closed with `not reproducible or was caused by typos` but I don't see typoes and IMHO it is a regex question that should not be closed or deleted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```py
import re
# joining so I could call findall one time on a multiline string.
# each line is treated as it's own input
authors = '\n'.join(["DiCAPRIO Leonardo Wilhelm", "MacGYVER Angus", "ANDERSON Richard Dean", "ZETA-JONES Catherine", "BONHAM CARTER Helena", "DOUGLASMichael"])

# matching the first name and what's before is definitely the last name
pattern = r'(.+?)[ -]*([A-Z][a-z]+ ?[A-Z]*[a-z]*)'

# returns a list of tuples
print(re.findall(pattern, authors))
```

The first names are easily matched by an uppercase than a serie of lowercase that's why I match the first name and what's before is the last name. a working example can be found [here](https://repl.it/join/oxofpiuh-heraclit)

---

## The output

```
[('DiCAPRIO', 'Leonardo Wilhelm'), 
 ('MacGYVER', 'Angus'),
 ('ANDERSON', 'Richard Dean'),
 ('ZETA-JONES', 'Catherine'),
 ('BONHAM CARTER', 'Helena'),
 ('DOUGLAS', 'Michael')]
```

Answer (score 1):

For this rather complicated example I would chose regex combined with `itertools.groupby`:

```
import re
from itertools import groupby


lst = [
    'DiCAPRIO Leonardo Wilhelm',
    'MacGYVER Angus',
    'ANDERSON Richard Dean',
    'ZETA-JONES Catherine',
    'BONHAM CARTER Helena',
    'DOUGLASMichael'
]

for v in lst:
    l = re.sub(r'([A-Z])([A-Z][a-z]+)$', r'\1 \2', v).split()
    out = [' '.join(g) for _, g in groupby(l, lambda k: bool(re.search(r'[a-z]$', k)))]
    print(out)
```

Prints:

```
['DiCAPRIO', 'Leonardo Wilhelm']
['MacGYVER', 'Angus']
['ANDERSON', 'Richard Dean']
['ZETA-JONES', 'Catherine']
['BONHAM CARTER', 'Helena']
['DOUGLAS', 'Michael']
```

Answer (score 1):

For the example data you might use 2 capturing groups, assuming the names start with an uppercase char A-Z

```
((?:Di|Mac)?[A-Z]{2,}(?:[ -][A-Z]{2,})*) ?([A-Z][^\WA-Z]+(?: [A-Z][^\WA-Z]+)*)
```

In parts

- `(` Capture **group 1**

  - `(?:Di|Mac)?` Optionally match `Di` or `Mac`
  - `[A-Z]{2,}` Match 2 or more chars A-Z
  - `(?:[ -][A-Z]{2,})*` Repeat 0+ times either a space or `-` and 2 or more chars A-Z
- `) ?` Close group 1 and match optional space
- `(` Capture **group 2**

  - `[A-Z][^\WA-Z]+` Match A-Z and 1+ times a word char except A-Z
  - `(?: [A-Z][^\WA-Z]+)*` Repeat 0+ times previous pattern with a space prepended
- `)` Close group 2

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/8XGszr/1) | [Python demo](https://ideone.com/kmzOZz)

For example

```
import re

arrayAuthors = [
    "DiCAPRIO Leonardo Wilhelm",
    "MacGYVER Angus",
    "ANDERSON Richard Dean",
    "ZETA-JONES Catherine",
    "BONHAM CARTER Helena",
    "DOUGLASMichael"
]

regex = r"((?:Di|Mac)?[A-Z]{2,}(?:[ -][A-Z]{2,})*) ?([A-Z][a-z]+(?: [A-Z][a-z]+)*)"

for author in arrayAuthors:
    print(re.findall(regex, author))
```

Output

```
[('DiCAPRIO', 'Leonardo Wilhelm')]
[('MacGYVER', 'Angus')]
[('ANDERSON', 'Richard Dean')]
[('ZETA-JONES', 'Catherine')]
[('BONHAM CARTER', 'Helena')]
[('DOUGLAS', 'Michael')]
```